# Added my Malt syrup and brought to a boil BEFORE my grain

Tags: boil, grain

So I was starting a new batch and completely distracted over bills etc and realized once my malt was boiling that I COMPLETELY forgot to add and steep my grain. I added them for about 10 minutes after even tho it was boiling. Any idea how this will affect the outcome?

Did I just completely mess this up or what? Still pretty new to brewing btw.
It was intended to be a Porter but not sure now.

Answer (score 1):

**Missed the steep**

Worse case scenario you extracted tannins from the husks (astringent mouth feel / bitter, not appropriate in any beer style). This happens when two conditions are met. 1) 170°F or above and 2) ph 6.0 or above.
It's possible the wort was a ph below 6.0, so I may be ok.

As far as sugar it's already been converted in most steeping grains, crystals etc so you're good there.

Possibly a little carmelizing giving malliard notes like biscuit etc, typical of decoction (old process of boiling part of the grist for temp stepping a mash)

*If it ever happens again, just stop the boil and reduce temp and hold at 160°F for 20 minutes while steeping*

Comment: Ya, in the end  im realizing there was no reason to panic and rush, i should have just removed it from boil as you mentioned. We shall see how it goes.  THANKS!

Comment: Alternately, you could consider heating some water on the stove and steeping your grains in that, then adding the additional wort to the boil later. You'll have to account for the additional volume, but if you're used to topping off your batch (fairly common with extract brews), you simply may have to add less top-up water at the end.